# Python convert doc to docx

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to convert doc file into docx. I found this code online.

```
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', filename])
document = docx.Document(path[:-4] + ".docx")
docText = ''.join([
    paragraph.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for paragraph in 
document.paragraphs
```

It works perfectly fine with I use it on my own machine but I am trying to put this one AWS. It doesn't work there. I get an error saying "No such file or directory".

What could be the reason that it works on my computer but when I put it on AWS it doesnt.

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback. I suspect you don't have `soffice` on your AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: How do you execute the code? Have you tried calling it via cmd line, and python where the file you want to convert sits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have LibreOffice installed in the machine where ever you are using this code and you must close open instances of LibreOffice before running this, or it will exit silently without doing anything.
You can also try

```
unoconv -d document --format=docx *.doc
```

But it also dependent on LibreOffice. It will convert the files through LibreOffice. It is imperfect, and some formatting is lost, but it will convert all doc files to docx

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I didnt have LibreOffice installed, that was the problem.